# Creating and storing a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm working on creating a session for a user login on my website. I can initialize the session and use its members just fine, but I also need a method within my session class that will store itself. I need to provide `HttpSessionState` as an input parameter, and then store it into an object like: `Session["sessionName"]=this;`.

Furthermore, when I want to retrieve the session, it won't yet be created, so it must be static. Then I need to return a new instance of my session class with the properties filled (username and companyID) out of the `HttpSessionState`.

How can this be done in my session class? What I've described above is from the research I've done that provides a particular solution to my problem, but since I'm new to using session, I don't quite understand it.
Thanks.

Snippet of my session class:

```
public class MySession : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private MySession()
        {
            Username    = Business.User.labelUsername;
            CompanyId   = Business.User.labelCompanyId;
        }

        public static MySession Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    MySession session = (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionName"];

                    if (session == null)
                    {
                        session = new MySession();
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionName"]=session;
                    }
                    return session;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("NullReferenceException:");
                    Debug.WriteLine(e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string CompanyId
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem that you're having, can you elaborate what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seems pretty apparent what the OP wants.  He needs to store his own object in session and bring it back on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a serialized "session info" object:

```
[Serializable]
public class SessionInfo
{
    // Stuff to store in session
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    private SessionInfo()
    {
        // Constructor, set any defaults here
        Name = ""
        Foo = 10;
    }

    public static SessionInfo Current
    {
        get
        {
            // Try get session info from session
            var info = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionInfo"] as SessionInfo;

            // Not found in session, so create and store new session info
            if (info == null)
            {
                info = new SessionInfo();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionInfo"] = info;
            }

            return info;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use this from within your application like this:

```
SessionInfo.Current.Name = "Something Here";
SessionInfo.Current.Foo = 100;
```

The serialization/deserialization is all done within the SessionInfo object, and you get the benefit of type safe data.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is called serialization and deserialization.

Serialization is taking an object and converting it to a format, such as a string, that can be stored.  Deserialization is the reverse of that action.

The "quick" way is to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to your class.  However, without knowing the details of that class it's hard to say whether it is in fact easily serializable without a bit of work.

Here's a walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/et91as27.aspx